# Send EmailMessage via REST API for Service Cloud

Tags: rest-api, servicecloud

I'm trying to send an email reply via the REST API for a case created in Service Cloud.

Creation of the emailMessage itself and the emailMessageRelation are working correctly.
Creation is done via POST to /data/v49.0/sobjects/EmailMessage/ and the message is visible on the case.

But i'm not receiving the actual email.
Do I need an extra send trigger? Is this done via those quickActions? how?

On the SOAP documention found on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_send_email_message.htm.
In the sample they create a draft and an extra sendEmailMessage call.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I'd overlooked that this was for REST, so I've made some updates below.

For Apex and SOAP, the sendEmailMessage() must be called on the constructed email.

REST seems to have a special endpoint for actions such as email.  See here for documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_email_simple.htm

or here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_actions_invocable_standard.htm?search_text=send%20email

Also note that email deliverability is often turned off in sandbox environments, which could cause the send to silently fail depending on how you handled the try/catch and SendEmailResult response.

I am surprised that the email is showing in the ui if not sent, though.  Somehow you've constructed the sobject record but not actually sent it.

Comment: Hi @jimG, how do I call sendEmailMessage() ?

Comment: It's actually in the SOAP doc link you included:  SendEmailResult[] = connection.sendEmailMessage( String[] draftEmailIds);

Comment: yes I know, but how can this be done via rest api call? not using the soap service for now.

Comment: Whoops, sorry.  A quick search is showing this REST endpoint, which is slightly different than the one you mentioned above:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_email_simple.htm

Comment: Hi JimG, looks like that is for sending a simple email. Will check later when i receive my proper sandboxes and production env, only have the developer version for now.