# EmailMessage in python successful but no email is actually sent

Tags: email2case, emailmessage

I am sending an email in a case using emailMessage in python. I can see it updated in the case but the email isnt actually sent. I have hardcoded the FromAddress and ToAddress.

My request is as follows:

```
import requests

import os

from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf_pass = os.environ['SALESFORCE_API_KEY'].split('!')[0] + '!'
sf_token = os.environ['SALESFORCE_API_KEY'].split('!')[1]
sf_user = os.environ['SALESFORCE_API_EMAIL']

sf = Salesforce(username=sf_user, password=sf_pass, security_token=sf_token)

session_id = sf.session_id

base_url = "https://mybaseurl.com"

case_id = "XXXXXXXXXXX"

email_subject = "This is working"

email = "to@address.com"

from_address = "from@address.com"

email_body = "Dear customer, \n\nWe have received your case and are working on it. We will update you soon with further information.\n\nBest Regards,\nThe Support Team"

email_payload = {
    "Subject": email_subject,
    "TextBody": email_body,
    "ParentId": case_id,
    "ToAddress": email,
    "FromAddress": from_address
}

url = f"{base_url}/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/EmailMessage"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {session_id}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=email_payload)

if response.status_code == 201:
    print(f"Email sent successfully!: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.json()}")
else:
    print(f"Failed to send email. Status code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.json()}")
```

Comment: Is that from scratch org? If so -- check if email address of an admin account is verified

Comment: No, its not a scratch org

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Your code snippet is sufficiently minimal but it's not complete or reproducible without additional information.

Comment: @identigral my apologies, I added all of the code above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send EmailMessage via REST API for Service Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317766/send-emailmessage-via-rest-api-for-service-cloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All posting a email message to

> /services/data/v58.0/sobjects/EmailMessage

will do is make a record on your org of that email message. This has nothing to do with actually sending the message you need to either:

1. make a trigger (flow/apex) to take this newly inserted email message and send it
2. call a standard invokable action remotely [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_actions_invocable_standard_get.htm)
3. make your own invokeable rest call in apex

Comment: Hi @KarlLivesey
Can the email created via simpleEmail be linked to a case?

Comment: @user2249295 Yes you can if in the input provided see link below for documentation you specify "logEmailOnSend" as true and specify the related record Id in "relatedRecordId" it will automatically log the email against this in salesforce on successful send and will appear in the timeline.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_email_simple.htm